# Instantiation classes in PHP OOP

Tags: php, autoload

I'm writing an application with about 10 classes to do different subjects. I have 2 options to instantiate them.
1- Having one file (or a base class) to instantiate all of them. In this way I'm sure that I instantiated all classes once and can use all of them everywhere. In this way I can use `__outoload()` instead of including files.

2- Instantiate needed class in each file separately.  Absolutely in this way, I need to include different files.

Which one of these ways are better? Why?

Comment: I do not understand the question. How does object instantiation have any bearing on where the code is saved on disk? Is this a question about autoloading versus explicit includes?

Comment: You probably need to look up what "instantiation" actually means and rephrase your question to make more sense.

Comment: @Niko, Why do you think I don't know what instantiation means?
I need to know how can I do it to get the best performance.

Comment: @MohammadBagherSaberi Your question seems a bit strange to me, that's why. Would you mind adding some example code to clarify what you're talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on a variety of factors, such as how much load your site is under. You don't want to load a bunch of unnecessary objects if your site experiences heavy usage. There are different opinions on where to instantiate PHP objects, but in my experience, it's best to `include()` (or `require()` or whatever) the file and then instantiate its object inside of its class file. So I will `include('class_A.php');` and then inside class_A.php I will `$object = new Object()'`. As a random bit of trivia, please note that the `_once()` functions (`include_once()` and `require_once()`) cost significantly more cycles than the plain vanilla versions.

Answer (score 0):

Use solution 2, one file per class, and use [php autoload](http://php.net/manual/fr/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Answer (score 0):

[Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#PHP_2) is your choice.

You have a master class (factory) which know how to instantiate each one of your classes

Comment: I'd argue that factory is rather a dirty solution for something that got it's own native handling through PHP.

Comment: The factory pattern is perfectly legit in cases where you need to build instances inside other classes to prevent tight coupling. @MarcinWolny

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to have them in separate files. It makes code 1000 times more clear.

For loading the php files you than use [__autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) (as you see: php even contains native support for this situation)